# Set focus to UserControl (c# UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, focus

I have a problem setting focus to my UserControl. I want the control to gain focus whenever it is clicked (pointer pressed event).

Here's the control:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="MyApp.MyControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MyApp"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="100"
d:DesignWidth="160"
Canvas.ZIndex="10"  
IsEnabled="True"
IsFocusEngagementEnabled="True"
AllowFocusOnInteraction="True"
UseSystemFocusVisuals="True">
...
</UserControl>
```

Whenever pointer is pressed I call this.Focus(FocusState.Pointer) in the code.
However the method always returns false (fails to set FocusState, which remains
as Unfocused). What should I do to set focus to my user control?

Comment: Quote: "Only UI elements that are interactive are typically enabled to receive keyboard focus. For example, a TextBox is interactive because the user can type text, whereas a TextBlock is not interactive because the text is read-only".  A UserControl is not interactive, it doesn't do anything meaningful when press keys on the keyboard.  Nor is it capable of showing a focus rectangle.  Which does beg the question why you *need* it to get the focus.

Comment: Not 100% sure a `UserControl` can be set as the focus. What's inside your `UserControl`? Maybe you could set the focus on that instead.

Comment: The user control(s) are logic gates that are made of paths/ellipsis. I simply wanted to have a border around the control and a few buttons visible whenever the control is focused but I guess if that's not a recommended/possible approach I'll find another one, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

try add  IsTapEnabled="True" IsTabStop="True"

https://codedocu.com/Details?d=1595&a=9&f=181&l=0&v=d&t=UWP:-Focus-and-Keyboard-Events-with-IsTabStop-=-true