# How to set focus to an element inside of user control on UWP?

Tags: xaml, uwp, user-controls, uwp-xaml

I created my own `UserControl`, inside of it, I placed a `ListView`. But When I set the `UserControl` to show, I can't set focus to `ListViewItem`. The Focus is still in the original page.

For how to show my `UserControl`, I use `Popup`.

```
Popup popup = new Popup();
popup.Child = this;
popup.IsOpen = true;
```

Comment: This may duplicate with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46773662/set-focus-to-usercontrol-c-uwp. But the original question is still unresolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a Focus for a `ListView` takes place when the `ListView` has been loaded into the visual tree and ready for interaction.

We assume that you have created a `UserControl` that contains a `ListView`, then the method for setting the Focus for the `ListView` should be done in the **UserControl_Loaded** or **ListView_Loaded** event.

```cs
public PopupControl()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    // Data init
    var _popup = new Popup();
    _popup.Child = this;
    _popup.IsOpen = true;
}

private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TestListView.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);
}
```

Best regards.

Comment: Thx. I finally found out, it's my ItemContainerStyle's problem.